# Consulta en cascada SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola tengo una duda respecto a si hay alguna forma de hacer una consulta en sql server de la siguiente forma:

Tengo una tabla con una unidad base, una unidad a convertir y un factor, es decir (`Unidadbase * Factor = UnidadaConvertir`).
Entonces necesito hacer una instrucción SQL para saber todas las posibles conversiones para una unidad aunque no aparezca directamente en la tabla, es decir por ejemplo en la tabla tengo `[Mililitros][litros][1000]` y en otra fila `[Mililitros][Decilitros][10]` `(unidad_base,Unidad_Convertir,Factor)`.

Necesito que si se desea convertir decilitros a litros la instrucción pueda buscar en todos los registros aquellos que de alguna forma se puedan convertir a la unidad en cuestión, sin importar el numero de conversiones previas que se tenga que hacer para llegar al resultado.

Comment: Puede compartirnos cuales metodos ha probado para resolver esta problema?

Comment: Eso es mucho procesamiento desperdiciado cuando se podrían tener los datos en la tabla. Al menos se deberían de tener todos en la misma dirección (de menor a mayor o de mayor a menor). Hacer cálculos en 2 direcciones es muy costoso.